# Rsync: Keep destination file unchanged if same checksum

Tags: rsync

Let's say we have following files:

```
 ~/Homepage $ ls -l harp_output/BingSiteAuth.xml harp_netlify/BingSiteAuth.xml 
 -rw-r--r-- 1 david david 81 14. Mai 07:58 harp_netlify/BingSiteAuth.xml
 -rw-r--r-- 1 david david 81 14. Mai 08:10 harp_output/BingSiteAuth.xml
```

The content of both files is identical:

```
~/Homepage $ cmp harp_output/BingSiteAuth.xml harp_netlify/BingSiteAuth.xml; echo $?
0
```

Therefore, **I want `harp_netlify/BingSiteAuth.xml` not to be changed due to the identical content.** With following command, however, the timestamp of the file on the destination side gets updated:

```
~/Homepage $ rsync -cav --delete harp_output/ harp_netlify/
```

The result is this:

```
~/Homepage $ ls -l harp_output/BingSiteAuth.xml harp_netlify/BingSiteAuth.xml 
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 81 14. Mai 08:10 harp_netlify/BingSiteAuth.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 81 14. Mai 08:10 harp_output/BingSiteAuth.xml
```

But, I want to have this:

```
~/Homepage $ ls -l harp_output/BingSiteAuth.xml harp_netlify/BingSiteAuth.xml 
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 81 14. Mai 07:58 harp_netlify/BingSiteAuth.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 81 14. Mai 08:10 harp_output/BingSiteAuth.xml
```

**But, if the checksum is differed rsync must update the timestamp.**

Comment: Will `--no-times` be helpful?

Comment: @Sraw: I mistakenly thought `--no-times` makes rsync to **never** update timestamps. I tried out your suggestion and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments you are passing to `rsync` are `-cav`; the problem you have is the "a" which expands to `-rlptgoD` as explained in the [man page](https://ss64.com/bash/rsync_options.html), leaving you with a final `-crlptgoDv` argument list passed to rsync.

The tricky part of that is the `p`, `t`, `g`, and `o`, which preserve the permissions (p), modification times (t) (which is what is causing the sync change in your current example), group (g), and owner (o).  If I understand your question correctly, what you want is:

```
rsync -crlDv --delete harp_output/ harp_netlify/
```

In this we preserve the "c" and "v" from your current  command, and using the "r" (for recursive sync"), the "l" to preserve symlinks, and the "D" to preserve devices and special files.  If all you want is to sync recursively based on checksums, and you don't care about links or special files, then "r" is enough; ie:

```
rsync -crv --delete harp_output/ harp_netlify/
```